# Corona SDK - Rotate "world" around the player

Tags: lua, rotation, coronasdk

I'm trying to create a simple game where the player controls a ship that moves around in the "world". The thing that makes this a little trickier is that I want to rotate the "world" around the ship when it turns, so that the ships front is always facing towards the top of the phone screen.

I've created a group that contains the "world" and the ship as well as a group that I call `cameraLayer` that "follows" the ship around. All of this works fine in the sense that I can move the ship around and always keep it in the center of the phone screen. However, I can't seem to get the `cameraLayer` to rotate properly in relation to the ships rotation.

Here's the code for the two groups:

```
physicsLayer = display.newGroup()
physicsLayer:insert(bg)
physicsLayer:insert(player)

cameraLayer = display.newGroup()
cameraLayer:insert(physicsLayer)
cameraLayer.rotation = 0
cameraLayer.xScale = 1
cameraLayer.yScale = 1
cameraLayer.anchorX = 0.5
cameraLayer.anchorY = 0.5
cameraLayer.x = centerX
cameraLayer.y = centerY
cameraLayer.angle = 0
```

Here's the move function:

```
local function move()

    player.x = player.x + Cos( Rad(player.angle) ) * 2
    player.y = player.y + Sin( Rad(player.angle) ) * 2 

    cameraLayer.x = cameraLayer.x - Cos( Rad(cameraLayer.angle) ) * 2
    cameraLayer.y = cameraLayer.y - Sin( Rad(cameraLayer.angle) ) * 2   

end
```

Here's the rotation function:

```
local function enterFrameListener(key)
    if holding then
        if leftKey.isFocus == true then
            player.angle = player.angle - 3
            player.rotation = player.rotation - 3

            cameraLayer.angle = cameraLayer.angle - 3
        elseif rightKey.isFocus == true then
            player.angle = player.angle + 3
            player.rotation = player.rotation + 3

            cameraLayer.angle = cameraLayer.angle + 3
        end
    else
        -- Not holding
    end
end
```

I've tried to research as much as possible, but I've not found anything that could help me resolve my problem. Any form of help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: What about your code above is not working? Does it not rotate at all?

I am after something similar. I don't want the world to rotate with the ship in my case, but I do want the camera to say with it. What examples/samples are you learning from? Thanks

Comment: Do you have a video that shows what happens with the current code?  I've done something similar : I keep the ship static and rotate the 'world' group behind the ship .. http://youtu.be/rqlgLxwu_DI

Comment: The code above actually works in the sense that the cameralayer follows the ship around (the ship is always in the center) and the ship moves and rotates properly. However, I run in to trouble when trying to rotate the camera acordingly to the ships rotation. The code above doesn't contain anything that changes the cameras rotation (I took it out because it wasn't working, but it was basically: cameraLayer.rotation = cameraLayer.rotation + 3 same as for the ship). I suspect it has something to do with the anchor points which the world rotates around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last comment jogged my memory - you need to continually adjust the anchor point of the world, so that it rotates around the point where your ship is.  I keep the ship above the world and reset the world anchor points with the code below - hopefully this will help!  :D

```
-- position the map in the viewport
function viewport:positionMap( x, y )
    aX = ( mapSize * 0.5 + x ) / mapSize
    aY = ( mapSize * 0.5 + y ) / mapSize
    self.map.anchorX = aX
    self.map.anchorY = aY
end
```

(The viewport object is a container clipping the world map)